# JavaScript: List values having same parent value only once

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js

So straight to the point. I have a problem where I get data from an api as an array of objects. each object includes one city and one district. cities and districts are objects containing name and id

```
  city: Object
    id: 3
    name: "Rathbury"
  district: Object
    id: 39
    name: "Bosnia and Herzegovina District"
```

**Update:** 
Input

```
[
  {
    "title": "Kris Lodge",
    "location_text": "5739 Jakob Prairie Suite 451\nWest Leraview, MI 35816",
    "latitude": "",
    "longitude": "",
    "phone_numbers": [
      "01648997890",
      "01038129111"
    ],
    "emails": [
      "christy.spinka@example.com",
      "yboyle@example.org"
    ],
    "city": {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Bernhardburgh"
    },
    "district": {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "Hong Kong Neighbourhood"
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Tanner Circles",
    "location_text": "4513 Patrick Junctions\nNorth Priceport, CT 05572-1565",
    "latitude": "",
    "longitude": "",
    "phone_numbers": [
      "01894655129",
      "01768939354",
      "01054035727",
      "01120801876"
    ],
    "emails": [
      "francisca56@example.org",
      "lloyd.hilpert@example.com",
      "aaliyah.rau@example.net"
    ],
    "city": {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Rathbury"
    },
    "district": {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Vanuatu Neighbourhood"
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Walsh Harbors",
    "location_text": "5300 McGlynn Flat\nGustaveville, PA 08941-6431",
    "latitude": "",
    "longitude": "",
    "phone_numbers": [
      "01330125574"
    ],
    "emails": [
      "qgreenholt@example.org",
      "isawayn@example.net",
      "jtillman@example.com"
    ],
    "city": {
      "id": 15,
      "name": "Wintheiserfort"
    },
    "district": {
      "id": 34,
      "name": "Armenia Neighbourhood"
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Botsford Villages",
    "location_text": "461 Zemlak Hollow Suite 549\nLangworthberg, NE 40867-0943",
    "latitude": "",
    "longitude": "",
    "phone_numbers": [
      "01955713451",
      "01819751112",
      "01366897031"
    ],
    "emails": [
      "stanton80@example.com"
    ],
    "city": {
      "id": 15,
      "name": "Wintheiserfort"
    },
    "district": {
      "id": 49,
      "name": "Liberia Neighbourhood"
    }
  }
]
```

A city can occur twice but not a district. How can I list districts within cities only once? Here is an image to show more details. How can I get to show `Mali Area` and `Bosnia and Herzegovina District` under the Amparoville once?
[image]

Comment: Take a look at [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (or use `forEach`). Post your attempt, tell us exactly what the input und output is, and where you're stuck.

Comment: @ChrisG I have updated the question and added the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want the collection to look, I think this solution could work for you.

```js
var data = [{
    city: {
      id: 3,
      name: "Amaporville"
    },
    district: {
      id: 39,
      name: "Bosnia and Herzegovina District"
    }
  },
  {
    city: {
      id: 3,
      name: "Rathbury"
    },
    district: {
      id: 38,
      name: "Montenegro Heights"
    },

  },
  {
    city: {
      id: 3,
      name: "Amaporville"
    },
    district: {
      id: 40,
      name: "Mali Area"
    }
  }
]


function transformArr(orig) {
  var newArr = [],
    cities = {},
    i, cur;
  for (i = 0; i < orig.length; i++) {
    cur = orig[i];
    if (!cities[cur.city.name]) {
      var obj = {}
      obj['city'] = cur.city
      cities[cur.city.name] = {
        districts: []
      };
      obj['districts'] = cities[cur.city.name].districts
      newArr.push(obj);
    }
    cities[cur.city.name].districts.push(cur.district);
  }
  return newArr;
}

console.log(transformArr(data))
```

Essentially you use a hash map and add cities to it. The city name points to a an array of districts. The cities object's purpose is to determine whether or not your collection already includes that city's name. If so, add current district to that items districts.

As you're organizing your hash map you also add the `city` key to `obj` and assign it the value of the current object's city object. You then do the same for the districts. At the end you will have all districts that belong to a city appearing underneath that city, rather than previously appearing twice (or however many times that city appears in the original collection).

Comment: I have updated the question with what is exactly the input. In vue, I added the transformArr as a function and called the function where needed. Yet, the page is not rendering. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Tes3awy when you say it's not rendering do you mean it's not rendering at all or not rendering the right information? Where in your Vue component is it being called and is it properly updating state?

Comment: It’s not rendering the whole component. I called the function as a computed property and loop through them. When I console log the computed property, it’s logged properly.

Comment: Is there any way you can share the code? Are there any errors?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. It was something stupid I made in vue which was preventing the component from rendering. Thanks again bro.